# Deploy error SQL01234: the database version is not supported, not able to deploy ..how can i solve this

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I am using VS2010 and SQL Server 2012, I am trying to deploy SQLCLR database project with simple code in VS its showing deploy failed and error is:

> The following error might appear if you deploy a SQL CLR project that
>   was built for a version of the .NET Framework that is incompatible
>   with the target instance of SQL Server: "Deploy error SQL01268: CREATE
>   ASSEMBLY for assembly failed because assembly failed verification". To
>   resolve this issue, open the properties for the project, and change
>   the .NET Framework version. C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\TeamData\Microsoft.Data.Schema.SqlClr.targets(96,5):
>   Deploy error SQL01234: The database version is not supported.
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:00.02
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>   ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: SQL Server **2012** using .NET 4 for it's SQL-CLR - earlier versions of SQL Server used .NET 2 - are you deploying against an earlier version of the SQL Server engine (2005, 2008, 2008 R2) by any chance?

Comment: Ensure .NET Framework 4 is installed in your machine. If not either update your windows or install .NET framework 4 from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=17876.

Comment: in my system ,using .Net 4 framework and VS 2010 and having both sql server 2012 and 2008 R2

Comment: So which of the two instances (2008 R2 or 2012) are you trying to deploy to??

Comment: marc_s@ SQL Server 2008 R2